# What lays out the Blazor WASM template MainLayout.razor <div>s as inline elements?

Tags: html, css, razor, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to learn how the Blazor WebAssembly (blazorwasm) template works.
I can't see what lays out the MainLayout.razor

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="http://blazor.net" target="_blank" class="ml-md-auto">About</a>
    </div>
```

as inline elements.
I'm even more puzzled when I insert

```
<div>
    <p>Why is this inline?</p>
</div>
```

between `<div class="sidebar">` and `<div class="main">` because that's also laid out as an inline element.

I understand `<div>` to be a block-level element that always starts on a new line.
I've searched the solution generated from the Blazor WebAssembly (blazorwasm) template and looked in the MSDN Blazor Layouts doco but can't find anything that lays out the block level `<div>`s as inline elements.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not laid out 'inline'.

The Blazor templates use css. In net5 the MainLayout.razor.css sets up the surrounding `<div class="page">` to use FlexBox and `flex-direction: column;` to achieve the overall layout.

Your `<div> ... </div>` is positioned as a flex column because of its parent element.

Comment: Thanks Henk.  Most appreciated.
I understand you to mean that MainLayout.razor is set-up as a Flex Container when the blazorwasm and blazorserver apps are created.  Is this correct? 
Following your answer I searched MSDN for some references and the only one I could find  was a no longer updated page titled "Flexible box layout (flexbox)" dated 10/20/2016.
Can you point me to any more recent MSDN doco that describes the process?
You mention MainLayout.razor.css. I've searched for it without success.  Where does it live?
Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: For CSS you go to Mozilla.org or maybe w3schools. With net5 in VS the css files are nested under the razor files, there is a little triangle you can click. With earlier Blazor versions, see wwwroot/css/site.css

Comment: Thanks Henk.  I've got it.